# Can a std::function store pointers to data members?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std-function, data-members

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), I found that:

> Class template std::function is a general-purpose polymorphic function wrapper. Instances of std::function can store, copy, and invoke any Callable target -- functions, lambda expressions, bind expressions, or other function objects, as well as pointers to member functions and **pointers to data members**.

I cannot see why a `std::function` should be able to store such a pointer and I've never heard before about that feature.
Is it really possible, I missed something or that's an error in the documentation?

How should the `operator()` behave in such a case?
As from the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function/operator()):

> Invokes the stored callable function target with the parameters args.

Anyway, there is no stored callable function target to invoke here. Am I wrong?

To be honest, I cannot even figure out what's the right syntax for such a function, otherwise I'd have written an example to test it.
How could the following template be used to define a pointer to data member?

```
template< class R, class... Args >
class function<R(Args...)>
```

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e7fda761edce7ece

Comment: Sorry, I misread. :(

Comment: Ok, so the idea is the same used for member methods: the signature is exactly the same, but for the first parameter that is the instance on which to invoke them. A similar approach can be used for data members, is it? Interesting.

Comment: `std::bind` can be assigned to a `std::function`.

Comment: @Alex So? `bind` returns a callable object, it's fine.

Comment: The data member could be a callable object.

Comment: @Otomo see the example in the first comment, that's not because of what you say, I'm sorry

Comment: @skypjack Yeah, I figured it out already.  Nice to know.

Comment: @skypjack [another example?](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f7c6f9953b04998)

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki A good one for sure, even more with a few details of context. That's a bounty for the sake of curiosity, so I'll assign it the last day, each example is welcome till that day. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The effect of a call to the function call operator of `std::function<R(ArgTypes...)>`:

```
R operator()(ArgTypes... args) const
```

is equivalent to (§ 20.9.11.2.4 [[func.wrap.func.inv]/p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.wrap.func.inv#1)):

```
INVOKE<R>(f, std::forward<ArgTypes>(args)...)
```

whose definition includes the following bullet (§ 20.9.2 [[func.require]/p1](http://eel.is/c++draft/func.require#1)):

> Define *INVOKE*(f, t1, t2, ..., tN) as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> <sup>1.3</sup> — `t1.*f` when `N == 1` and `f` is a pointer to member data of a class `T` and `t1` is an object of type `T` or a
>   reference to an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of a type derived from `T`;

then, when `f` is a pointer to a data member stored in an internal invoker of a `std::function`, then the `std::function` itself should define a single argument, e.g.:

```
std::function<int(std::pair<int,int>)> f = &std::pair<int,int>::first;

f(std::make_pair(1, 2));
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d5f342aeb7def86)

Comment: Being the return type of the *function* the actual type of the data member, right?

Comment: That `R` at the end of *INVOKE* means "*implicitly convertible to R*", so the type of the stored data member can be convertible to what `std::function` defines

Comment: Wow, even more powerful than what I guessed. Still I can't see any real use of such a feature, but this cannot lessen its beauty!! Really thank you for your responses, as usual, very appreciated. :-)

Comment: @skypjack They are very useful as projections.

Comment: @T.C. It sounds interesting and you know that I want to understand!! :-) ... Would it be possible that you add one more answer with such an example of use? It will have my upvote for sure.